# Yammer and Jetpack for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, yammer, jetpack

I would like to create a share button on my Wordpress blog with Jetpack plugin.
This service is not included by default. So, what is the Yammer sharing url or link to documentation?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a Yammer share Button using this script:

```
<span id="yj-share-button"></span>
```

Place the following code at the bottom of the page before the closing  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s0.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_social_buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">yam.platform.yammerShare();</script>
```

Ref: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/share-button

Answer (score 0):

I read that, but it's not compatible with Jetpack for Wordpress...
I would like ti create my own custom sharing button: https://jetpack.com/support/sharing/